# Non-restoring Floating Point Square Root Algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, floating-point

I am trying to use the non-restoring algorithm for computing the square root of a floating point number.

For instance, say `x = 1001`, the square root is `31.6386`

**I want to calculate this square root** *using the non-restoring method*.

I tried following the method in the paper:

> [Implementation of Single Precision Floating Point Square Root on FPGAs](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?arnumber=624623)

but it appears my result is slightly off by 1 bit. I'm not able to figure out why though.

For instance, the program I wrote below will produce the following results:

```
correct_result =
  41FD1BD2

myresult =  
  41FD1BD1

error =    
    1.192093e-007
```

**`C++ version of the code`** :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

  union newfloat{
    float f;
    int i;
  };

int main () {
// Input number
newfloat x;
cout << "Enter Number: ";
cin >> x.f;

// Pull out exponent and mantissa
int exponent = (x.i >> 23) & 0xFF;
int mantissa = (x.i & 0x7FFFFF) | ((exponent && exponent) << 23);

// Calculate new exponent
int new_exponent = (exponent >> 1) + 63 + (exponent & 1);


// Shift right (paper says shift left but shift left doesn't work?)
if (exponent & 1) {
    mantissa = mantissa  >> 1;
    cout << " Shifted right " << endl;
}

// Create an array with the bits of the mantissa
unsigned int D [48];
for (int i = 47; i >= 0; i--) {
  if (i >= 24) {
    D[i] = (mantissa >> (i-24)) & 1;
  } else {
    D[i] = 0;
  }
}


// == Perform square root ==
// Set q24 = 0, r24 = 0 and then iterate from k = 23 to 0
int q[25] = {0}; // 25 element array, indexing ends at 24
int r[25] = {0};

for (int k = 23; k >= 0; k--) {
    if (r[k+1] >= 0) {
        r[k] = ((r[k+1] << 2) | (D[2*k+1] << 1) | D[2*k] ) - (q[k+1] << 2 | 1 );
        } else {
        r[k] = ((r[k+1] << 2) | (D[2*k+1] << 1) | D[2*k] ) + (q[k+1] << 2 | 0x3 );
        } 

    if (r[k] >= 0) {
        q[k] = (q[k+1] << 1) | 1;
        } else {
        q[k] = q[k+1] << 1;
    }

    if (k == 0) {
        if (r[0] < 0) {
            r[0] = r[0] + (q[0] << 1) | 1;
        }
    }
}

// Create quotient from LSBs of q[]
int Q = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <= 23; i++) {
    Q = Q | ((q[i] & 1) << i);
}

// Option 1 Rounding
//if (r[0] > 0) // Works for 10, 1001, 1021, but not 1012
// Q = Q + 1;

// Option 2 Rounding (No rounding)
// Works for 1012, Doesn't work for 10, 1001, 1021

// Option 3 Rounding (Calculate the next 3 Quotient bits to get a guard round and sticky bit)

// Calculate correct result:
newfloat correct_result;
correct_result.f = sqrt(x.f);

// Form my result into a single number
newfloat myresult;
myresult.i = (new_exponent << 23) | (Q & 0x7FFFFF);

// Print results
cout << hex << "My result: " << myresult.i << endl;
cout << hex << "Correct:   " <<  correct_result.i << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't know the answer, but strongly suspect it will be a lot easier to check your code for a mistake and help you with that one part than write a long tutorial on the technique (which you already have the basics of in the paper). Please show the relevant parts of your code.

Comment: It is not clear which paper you are using as the basis for your work. Have you looked at this: Anuja Nanhe, Gaurav Gawali, Shashank Ahire, and K. Sivasankaran: Implementation of Fixed and Floating Point Square Root Using Nonrestoring Algorithm on FPGA. International Journal of Computer and Electrical Engineering, Vol. 5, No. 5, October 2013, pp. 533-537.

Comment: @njuffa, I've updated the paper link, it is stated in the question. I looked at that paper, but the algorithm is slightly confusing due to the poor English. Also, I don't want to start focusing on another paper.

Comment: Where's the code for `convertnum2fpparts`, `combinefpparts`, etc.? Your code isn't runnable. Have you checked that the outputs from that function are correct? Another thing to look for is if some calculation is being done with doubles when you wand single precision –it looks like you've tried to do this, but it can be tricky. Stick some calls to `whos` or `class` in there to check. Another think to look for is `0`- vs. `1`-based indexing errors. Your code sets `a=1001`, but your question refers to a value of `1000`, which one is used to produce the hex values shown?

Comment: @horchler, I added the missing code. I have checked those outputs you refer to, they are correct. I also meant for the code to set a = 1001. Some values provide correct results, some wrong, so that is why the code set a = 1001, because it is a value showing a wrong result. The code does indeed run, let me know if you experience problems. I am running MATLAB R2010a. Newer versions might have problems with the bitor command as it works with different parameters in the newer versions.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking through the c++ version of your program and reading that document today. It seems to me that the algorithm is intended to provide both a quotient and a remainder. As in the example provided, he uses his algorithm to get the square root of 127, to which it provides a result of 11 + R 6. 11<sup>2</sup> + 6 = 127.

That was with an integer, but every data type has a limit to its precision. This leads me to believe that your program is executing as expected, its just that you've run out of precision, at least for the way the square root is being calculated, and for the data type being used. I expect you would find your minute "lost" precision in r[0].

I saw from the comments in the code that you intended to, or tried to calculate out extra precision. That seems like a reasonable path to try. Do note that, in addition to the other changes that would be required to do this, you would have to take out (or move) the check k == 0; since it modifies the remainder, which would mess up the loop.

I think the real question is what size precision is acceptable to you. For instance, the c++ sqrt function (and yours) are off by 0.00000002 on sqrt(2). No one seems to mind. Considering the program you wrote is off from the c++ sqrt function by less than that in the instances where it doesn't match. I spent the majority of the day breaking it down, testing the individual parts, and reviewing the subject matter, and couldn't find anything blatantly wrong. It seem close enough for government work to me.

Answer (score 1):

First let me highlight the relevant part from the paper:

[image: algorithm]

You need to take another look at how the additions/subtractions are done. You code is performing it in regular double-numbers, but I think the algorithm is designed with integer [modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) in mind.

So if you look at the example listed later in the paper, the computation of `0011 - 0101` wraps around to give `1110`.

[image: example]

That could explain why you're getting the wrong results, I think :)

Comment: I added a C++ version of the code using integer arithmetic, but I'm still not getting the correct result. Maybe there is an issue with the rounding? Any thoughts?

Comment: @starbox: I think you misunderstood the notations used in the paper (I don't blame you, it is not easy to read)... For one, there is a difference between `r(k)` and `R(k)` (same for `q` and `Q`). The capital letters denote individual bits, while the small letters are sequence of bits...

Comment: @starbox: I tried my hand at implementing the algorithm the way I understood it (the integer case, not the floating-point case). It gave correct results for many inputs, but there were wrong results as well... I'm not sure what I did wrong either! I could post my version if you want.